# How can I create a subcomponent to use with vue router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

First, I'm new to `vue.js`, so I apologize if my question is a bit basic. My `App.vue` is:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

I have a `router.js`, which has:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import Container from "./components/Container.vue";
import Home from "./components/Home.vue";
import Login from "./components/Login.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            component: Container,

        },
    ],
});
```

The idea is that `Container` has navigation, and should be used for various components (including `Home`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you have a `App.vue` containing `router-view`, you need a `Container` component to contain another `router-view` component. This will create a nested router views.

Once you do that, you will need to add children routes:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login,
        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: Container,
            children: [
                {
                    // LEAVE THIS PATH BLANK. Matches /home
                    path: '',
                    name: 'home',
                    component: HomeComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'another-route',
                    name: 'nested-route',
                    component: AnotherComponent,
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
});
```

> The key is to add children routes and leave one of the children with a blank path.